# How can Adelaide talk?

Tags: plot-explanation, us

In [Us (2019)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Us_(2019_film)), at the end of the movie we came to know that Adelaide was the clone for Red. Clones only shout throughout the film but Adelaide can talk like a human, how is that possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's shown within the movie that when Adelaide is found by the parents after the incident in the fun house / hall of mirrors, Adelaide is mute. They visit a doctor. The doctor explains that after severe trauma, young children sometimes lose the ability to speak. That's actually just the doctor's diagnosis of what he thinks *must* have happened, when the truth is that Adelaide is a clone who has *never* been able to speak.

Adelaide is then given speech classes to learn how to speak "again". All of her clone-related personality traits (inability to speak, lack of normal social skills, possible unfamiliarity with the parents), are all attributed to her traumatic experience in the fun house.